# Criar lista de entidades em FormBuilder

Tags: php, symfony-2

Eu tenho um CRUD de Usuario e um CRUD de permissões.
A ideia agora é adicionar uma tab no CRUD do usuarioa para permitir selecionar permissões.
 A ideia inicial é ter uma lista completa de todos as possiveis permissões com um checkbox uma ao lado da outra. Então o usuário pode selecionar as permissões que desejar sem a necessidade de abrir um dialogo modal ou algo do genero.

No back-end nós pegamos todos os checkboxes checados e fazemos uma iteração para dar os devidos INSERTS/DELETES na tabela de user_permission.

Em PHP plano isto seria algo como:

```
<?php
$permissions = retrieveAllPermissions();
foreach($permissions as $permission) {
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" value="' . $permission->id . '">';
  echo $permission->name;
  echo '<br>';
}
```

```
// processamento POST
$permissionsChecked = $_POST['permissions'];
// Algum logica para deletar e inserir novamente as permissoes
```

Como posso obter este resultado com Symfony?

> EDIT 26/03/2015

A relação das tabelas é many-to-many com uma tabela relacional.Desta forma:
usuario
permissao
usuario_permissao

Comment: Nossa, que gafe a minha! Achei que estava no soEN. hehe, vou editá-la :)

Comment: Como é o relacionamento no banco de dados entre um usuário e uma permissão? Many-to-many com tabela relacional?

Comment: Isto mesmo. Many-to-Many com uma tabela relacional.
Vou editar a pergunta e adicionar esta informação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É bem fácil.

Suponhamos que você tenha duas entidades, uma `User` e uma `Permission`, e um relacionamento `ManyToMany` entre elas:

Classe `User`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Permission")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_permission",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="permission_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     */
    protected $permissions;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->permissions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add permissions
     *
     * @param Permission $permission
     * @return User
     */
    public function addPermission(Permission $permission)
    {
        $this->permissions[] = $permission;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove permissions
     *
     * @param Permission $permission
     */
    public function removePermission(Permission $permission)
    {
        $this->permissions->removeElement($permission);
    }

    /**
     * Get permissions
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getPermissions()
    {
        return $this->permissions;
    }
}
```

Classe `Permission`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Permission
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Permission
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

O relacionamento `ManyToMany` que eu criei é unidirecional pois só me interessa saber as permissões a partir do usuário – e não o contrário.

Depois, criamos o `Form` para criação de um usuário. Nesse `Form`, definimos que é possível relacionar uma ou mais `Permission` em um `User`.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('permissions', null, [
                'property' => 'name'
            ]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

Finalmente, criamos o *controller* para manipular as requisições de alteração de permissões para um determinado usuário:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\UserType;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration as Sensio;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Sensio\Route("/user/{user}/permissions")
     */
    public function userPermissionsAction(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);
        $form->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Salvar permissões'));

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->render('user/permissions.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
}
```

O formulário ficará assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando adicionamos e removemos as permissões do usuário por meio desse formulário, é possível ver nos logs da aplicação as *queries* do Doctrine.

Adicionando permissões:

```
[2015-03-26 12:57:14] doctrine.DEBUG: "START TRANSACTION" [] []
[2015-03-26 12:57:14] doctrine.DEBUG: INSERT INTO user_permission (user_id, permission_id) VALUES (?, ?) [1,1] []
[2015-03-26 12:57:14] doctrine.DEBUG: INSERT INTO user_permission (user_id, permission_id) VALUES (?, ?) [1,2] []
[2015-03-26 12:57:14] doctrine.DEBUG: INSERT INTO user_permission (user_id, permission_id) VALUES (?, ?) [1,3] []
[2015-03-26 12:57:14] doctrine.DEBUG: "COMMIT" [] []
```

Removendo permissões:

```
[2015-03-26 12:58:09] doctrine.DEBUG: "START TRANSACTION" [] []
[2015-03-26 12:58:09] doctrine.DEBUG: DELETE FROM user_permission WHERE user_id = ? [1] []
[2015-03-26 12:58:09] doctrine.DEBUG: "COMMIT" [] []
```

Espero ter ajudado. :)